# ActiveRecord: make query using model from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a string containing a set of ActiveRecord models and I would like to do the same query for every model passed as string.

```
model_type = 'Comment'
id = 1
record = model_type.find(id)

model_type = 'Post'
id = 1
record = model_type.find(id)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `constantize` method.

```
model_type.constantize.find(id)
```

Do be careful when accepting arbitrary user data and evaluating it like this. You may generate exceptions for unknown classes.

Answer (score 1):

`constantize` nice, I hadn't seen that one before.  Here's how I've done it in the past:

```
@list = Kernel.const_get(@type).find_by_id_and_account_id(params[:id], current_account.id)
```

I'm not sure which is better, `constantize` looks cleaner :)